# How to maintain table row height in scrolling window - Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a html table with static headers. The rest of the body scrolls within a fixed size window. (Using overflow:scroll; height:550px; overflow-x:hidden; for the tbody )

When the number of rows is less than what fits in the scrolling window, the row size automatically expands to fill the entire scroll window. How do I "disable this"?

For example, with only 1 row in the table, the height of that one row becomes (gigantic) the height of the scrolling window.

How do I maintain the original row height, even is it is the only row in the scrolling window? I attempted to use the CSS height property for all `<td>`but it didn't take.

(FYI - In IE, the original row size is kept.)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with original row size being kept in IE? This doesn't work at all in IE.

Comment: using this method for IE - http://geekswithblogs.net/LSheu/archive/2009/01/30/css-table-scrolling-with-fixed-header-for-ie-7.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you confusing the both browsers with each other? It works flawlessly in FF, but the problems you describe are recognizeable as from IE. It doesn't support an `overflow` on the `tbody` that way. There are however (nasty) workarounds/hacks to get this to work in all of the current browsers, including IE:

- Google:  "[scrollable table with fixed header](http://www.google.com/search?q=scrollable+table+with+fixed+header)"
- Stackoverflow: "[scrollable table with fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrollable+table+with+fixed+header)"

**Edit**: as turns out from your comments, you're already using a workaround for this and you thus have problems in FF? Well, I would try another workaround/hack then. For example [this](http://fixedheadertable.mmalek.com) or [this](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/66-table-styling-2-fixed-header-and-highlighting/). Only ensure that you're using the right (strict) doctype.

Answer (score 1):

Use the min-height css option.  You'll have to do a bit of hacking to make it work in IE6 (mostly just do an underscore hack for height "_height:XXpx").

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work....(Don't need it to work in IE have separate style sheet and by default this problem doesn't exist.)